# AppleScript use Safari window ID to create new tabs

Tags: safari, applescript

I have an AppleScript that creates a new Safari document, then opens multiple URLs in that window using a repeat loop. I would like the script to continue using the same window even if it's not the frontmost window.

(The problem is that if a user changes focus to another Safari window this script will open the URLs in the frontmost window instead of the previously created window.)

I would like to solve this issue by using the `window id` if possible but need some help on the scripting.

To that end I have created the following but again I think there might be an issue. I would rather not get the id using `front window` since a user could change the front window at an inopportune time and the script would pull the wrong window ID.

```
tell application "Safari"
    make new document -- after this what if user changes focus
    set win_ID to id of front window of application "Safari"
end tell
```

I would rather use something like

```
set win_ID to window id of (make new document)
```

Even using the above I have been unable to open URLs in a window by using it's window id and need help with that scripting as well.

It would function something like this:

```
tell application "Safari"
    open location "https://apple.com" in a new tab in window id xxxx
end tell
```

Comment: Just an FYI.. I've modified the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ in my answer to use the `window id` directly and avoid using the `index` _property_ of the `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update to address concerns of the use of: `front window`

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* guarantees the *list* of **URL**s gets opened in the target *window* regardless of its *position* in the *z-order* of *windows*.

```applescript
set myURLs to {¬
    "https://apple.com", ¬
    "https://google.com", ¬
    "https://superuser.com", ¬
    "https://example.com"}

set windowName to random number from 1000000 to 9999999
set tmpFileName to "/private/tmp/" & windowName & ".html"
set tmpFileContent to "<html><head><title>" & windowName & "</title></head></html>"

if not my writeToFile(tmpFileContent, tmpFileName, true) then return

tell application "Safari"
    
    make new document with properties {URL:"file://" & tmpFileName}
    set i to 0
    repeat while not (exists (windows whose name is windowName))
        delay 0.1
        set i to i + 1
        if i = 30 then return
    end repeat
    set winID to (id of windows whose name is windowName) as number
    
    make new tab at end of tabs of window id winID with properties {URL:item 1 of myURLs}
    delete first tab of window id winID
    repeat with i from 2 to (length of myURLs)
        make new tab at end of tabs of window id winID with properties {URL:item i of myURLs}
        delay 1
    end repeat
    
end tell

tell application "System Events" to delete file tmpFileName


--  # Handler #

on writeToFile(theData, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)
    try
        set theFile to theFile as string
        if theFile contains "/" then
            set theOpenedFile to open for access theFile with write permission
        else
            set theOpenedFile to open for access file theFile with write permission
        end if
        if overwriteExistingContent is true then set eof of theOpenedFile to 0
        write theData to theOpenedFile starting at eof
        close access theOpenedFile
        return true
    on error
        try
            close access file theFile
        end try
        return false
    end try
end writeToFile
```

<sup>**Note:** Scroll as needed to see all the *code*.</sup>

---

**Notes:**

- The updated *example* **AppleScript** *code* includes some *error handling*, in that if the *tmp file* (value of the `tmpFileName` *variable*) is not created the *script* aborts without any message. This can be changed by converting the `if not my writeToFile ...` *statement* to a full `if` *block* and include an appropriate `display alert`, `display dialog` or `display notification` *command*, as wanted, followed by the `return` *command*.
- As coded, this renders `--> document "Untitled"` returned from the `make new document` irrelevant, because with the included `repeat` *loop* it waits until the **HTML** *file* is loaded and can be queried by the actual *name* of the *document* as defined by the `<title>" & windowName & "</title>` *tags* in the document and ensures that the *z-order* is irrelevant.
- The `repeat` *loop* as coded is written to wait up to 3 seconds for the **HTML** *file* to load and should be more than enough time. Adjust if necessary.
- I opted to forgo the use of the `do shell script` *command* as used in your answer, however, if you prefer to use it, then:

**Replace:**

```applescript
if not my writeToFile(tmpFileContent, tmpFileName, true) then return
```

**With:**

```applescript
set shellCMD to {"echo '", tmpFileContent, "' > '", tmpFileName, "'"} as string
do shell script shellCMD
```

Then remove the `on writeToFile(theData, theFile, overwriteExistingContent)` *handler* from the `--  # Handler #` *section* of the *code*.

Additionally, if you prefer a `do shell script` *command* to remove the *tmp file*, the *value* of the `tmpFileName` *variable*, then:

**Replace:**

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to delete file tmpFileName
```

**With:**

```applescript
do shell script "rm " & tmpFileName's quoted form
```

---

**Original Answer**

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* is an example of how to open a *list* of **URLs** in the same *window* of **Safari**, regardless of its *window* order.

**Notes:**

- Do not use `open location` as it's a part of **Standard Additions**, not **Safari**. Use the `URL` *property* to set the **URL** of the *document* or *tab*.
- Use a `list` of **URLs** and the *index* of the *list item* (**URL**) in the *list*.
- When **Safari** is instructed to `make new document`, the *new document* becomes the `front window` of **Safari**. Get the `window id` of the `front window` immediately after the `make new document` *command*.
- For subsequent **URLs** in the *list*, start the `repeat` *loop* at `2` and use  the `window id` which was ascertained directly after the `make new document` *command* was executed.

```applescript
set myURLs to {¬
    "https://apple.com", ¬
    "https://google.com", ¬
    "https://superuser.com", ¬
    "https://example.com"}

tell application "Safari"
    
    make new document with properties {URL:item 1 of myURLs}
    set winID to id of front window
    
    repeat with i from 2 to (count myURLs)
        make new tab at end of tabs of window id winID with properties {URL:item i of myURLs}
        delay 1
    end repeat
    
end tell
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this so the newly created window has a location, front or back, and also has bounds?

Comment: @John, For changing the _position/size_ of the _window_ you can use the `bounds` _command_ after the `set winID to id of front window` _command_, e.g., `set bounds of window id winID to {0, 23, 1024, 768}`. However, setting the _position_ of the _window_, the _value_ of the `index` of the _window_ is not so straightforward, as it can depend on how many _windows_ and what _position_ you want to move the _front window_ to.

Comment: @John, Have a look at [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/233687/how-can-i-send-the-currently-active-window-to-the-back/262805#262805), you can take the lines of _code_ from within the `tell application "Finder"` _block_ and use that code to move the newly created _window_ to the back of the _z-order_. You could add it after the. `set winID to id of front window` _command_ or the, e.g., `set bounds of window id winID to {0, 23, 1024, 768}` _command_.

Answer (score 0):

@user3439894 I accepted your answer - it answers the question well. There is another way - a hackie way to create an ID for a Safari window.

This allows the following commands to avoid using "front window" in case the window that was created is no longer frontmost when the rest of the commands begin - doubtful, but possible.

I am not sure there is a way to give a new window anything other than "Untitled" as a name while creating the window.

```applescript
## you could use: set x to(time/date combo) instead, and then use variable x in the touch command and "make new document with properties"
do shell script "touch '/private/tmp/uniquename.txt'"
tell application "Safari"
    make new document with properties {URL:"file:///private/tmp/uniquename.txt"}
    set winID to (id of window {name:"uniquename.txt"}) -- this guarantees that the window we just created is the window we are going to add tabs to
    set x to properties of window id winID -- let's take a peek at it's properties
end tell
x
```

Replies:

```applescript
tell current application
    do shell script "touch '/private/tmp/uniquename.txt'"
        --> ""
end tell
tell application "Safari"
    make new document with properties {URL:"file:///private/tmp/uniquename.txt"}
        --> document "Untitled"
    get id of window {name:"uniquename.txt"}
        --> 30049
    get properties of window id 30049
        --> {zoomable:true, closeable:true, zoomed:true, class:window, index:1, visible:true, name:"Untitled", miniaturizable:true, id:30049, miniaturized:false, resizable:true, bounds:{0, 23, 800, 423}, current tab:tab 1 of window id 30049, document:document "Untitled"}
end tell
Result:
{zoomable:true, closeable:true, zoomed:true, class:window, index:1, visible:true, name:"Untitled", miniaturizable:true, id:30049, miniaturized:false, resizable:true, bounds:{0, 23, 800, 423}, current tab:tab 1 of window id 30049 of application "Safari", document:document "Untitled" of application "Safari"}
```

Comment: John, Please see the **Update to address concerns of the use of: `front window`** section of my updated answer. Borrowing  the _concept_ from your answer I incorporated it into a fully functioning update of my original answer. Thanks.